# How to Encode a web address

Tags: encryption, web, encoding, base64

```
data:text/html;base64,77u/data:text/html;base64,77u/PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+CjxodG1sIGxhbmc9ImVuLVVTIiBjbGFzcz0ia
```

I saw a url as the one above.

what is it called ?

how do i encrypt a url to be like that ?

Comment: It's called base64 encoding; what's encoded is not a web address, but actual HTML content itself. Note that it's trivially easy to decode, though.

Comment: So how can one do that?

Comment: You can decode base4 using a base64 decoder (or rather codec as most base64 components contain both a encoder and decoder).

Comment: I've kept the encryption tag because you obviously assumed encryption even if it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

It's called [base64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64); what's encoded in your example is not a web address, but actual HTML content itself.

Note that it's trivially easy to decode for anyone. Base64 is not suitable for "encrypting" resources. You can not hide content or URLs from your visitors this way.

Using this makes sense only in a very limited set of situations, like when you want to reduce the number of HTTP requests and store multiple resources inside one HTML page.

If you still want to use it  - there are online base64 encoders and decoders like [this one.](https://www.base64decode.org/) You'd use what you have above and replace everything after `base64,`.